# How to determine if JEST is running the code or not?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I am creating a JS test on my react-native project. I'm specifically using firebase for react native, in which I would like to replace firebase instance with a mockfirebase instance if JS is running the code of my class.

For example I have class setup like below.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
class Database() {
    /// use the firebase instance
}
```

I'd like to have a check if jest is the running environment then I'd replace the import line with appropriate mock class.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

jest sets an environment variable called JEST_WORKER_ID so you check if this is set:

```
function areWeTestingWithJest() {
    return process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID !== undefined;
}
```

I also see that if NODE_ENV is not set the jest CLI sets it to the value 'test'. This might be another way to check.

Comment: JEST_WORKER_ID wasn't set for me, but NODE_ENV was.

Comment: If you you Next.js's export feature `JEST_WORKER_ID` will defined in production too since it seems to use jest-worker module for it.

Comment: Why do you want to evaluate it each time if it never changes? Better to store it in a const.

Comment: I do this `process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID === undefined || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test'`

Answer (score 24):

I usually have `NODE_ENV=development` set globally on my shell. This works for me:

```
typeof jest !== 'undefined'
```

(note that `global.jest` and `'jest' in global` don't work, as this doesn't seem to be a global variable, just a value made available on all modules much like node's `require` or `__filename`)

Comment: In my React Native setup, `typeof jest !== 'undefined'` is false (i.e. it is defined) when running in the iOS simulator, attached to the debugger, so I had to check the worker ID as shown in the other answer.

Comment: On other environments I've tried this in, this also fails for some reason. There seems to be some diversity in whether this variable is available.

Answer (score 2):

you could add parameter to `global` for example global.isJest and check on the front end if it is defined

Answer (score 0):

For me best way is checking two things - `0` and `undefined`:

`[0, undefined].includes(process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID)`

so it's based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231746/3012785

Comment: It doesn't work from a type-checking perspective.
TS complains about the `includes` method because expectations are different since the left is a combination of [`string` and `number`], but the other side is globally considered a string.

Comment: So you decided to give me a minus. Cool

Comment: @Masoud you can change the 0 number to a string: '0'