# How to detect which test framework is running the code

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs, mocha.js

I wrote a small library to enhance the testing of my web app and now want to abstract it away into a separate open-source project. The library is generic enough that it would be useful not just for myself on other projects but also for others.

The only problem is that it implements a set of custom matchers and some jest-specific logic (this is done as a convenience to make actual test code less verbose). Implementing equivalent logic for other test frameworks should be straight-forward, but I'm struggling to understand how to consistently identify which test framework is running (to select correct assertion logic).

I know jest sets certain environment variables ([How to determine if JEST is running the code or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940640/how-to-determine-if-jest-is-running-the-code-or-not)), but based on the answer the jest-specific variable is not consistently set and `NODE_ENV` would be set to the same `test` value by all test frameworks. What's the cleanest approach for detecting which test framework is executing the test? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at all of the environment variables, seeing which ones are consistent and which aren't, here is a function I put together for determining the launcher/framework:

```
const path = require('path');
function detectFramework() {
  const launcher = process.env._;
  return path.basename(launcher);
}
```

This will work regardless of how you nickname your launch script in `package.json`. Hopefully someone else finds this useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use `process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID` constant.
Something like:

```
if(process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID) {
    //You are in test mode.
}
```