# jest with log4js console appender appends "console.log" and a dummy stack

Tags: node.js, jestjs

When I run my `jest` tests which use `log4js`'s console appender, each output line is littered with `console:` and a small stack trace (output and code below), which make it harder to follow the log flow.

**Question:** How do I get rid of these text additions?

**Current solution:** Replace type to `type: 'stdout'` solves this. ***[Edit]*** But then, when running the code not through jest, the log output doesn't appear under vscode's "Debug Console"

**Notes:**

- This does not happen when running just node code - only within jest.
- Adding `enableCallStack: false` to the category - doesn't change anything
- Adding `layout` to the appender affects the line (`[2021-12-28T13:12:20.334] [INFO] default - myinfo`), but the surrounding lines remain.

**Versions:** Node.js v14.18.1, jest@26.6.3, log4js@6.3.0

### Output

```
PS > node --experimental-vm-modules .\node_modules\jest\bin\jest
(node:21824) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 PASS  ./test.spec.js
  √ testname (13 ms)

  console.log                   <<<<<< want to get rid of this
    [2021-12-28T13:12:20.334] [INFO] default - myinfo     <<<<<< want to keep only this

      at node_modules/log4js/lib/appenders/console.js:6:5   <<<<<< want to get rid of this
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)   <<<<<< want to get rid of this
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)   <<<<<< want to get rid of this

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.366 s
```

### Code

```
import log4js from 'log4js';
log4js.configure({
    appenders: { console: { type: 'console' } },
    categories: { default: { appenders: [ 'console' ], level: 'trace' } }
  });

let logger = log4js.getLogger();

test('testname', () => {
    logger.info("myinfo");
});

// my actual code
function myActualCode
```

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen, Jest decorates them so you can distinguish your code's logging from its own. If you use the stdout transport that bypasses the console object and therefore Jest's decoration.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a strange design choice to add these 5 lines for each log line, especially the unhelpful stack trace - I'd expect a simple `console:` or something. Still, if this is the intended design, I guess I'll keep my solution of using of stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe noted, this is by design in jest. For reference: This is implemented in `node_modules\@jest\console\build\getConsoleOutput.js`

My solution: [Detect whether running under jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940640/), and if so switch to stdout:

```
log4js.configure(
    {
        appenders: {
            myAppender: {
                type: (process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID) ? 'stdout' : 'console',
                layout: ...
```